# Tensor vector identity $\vec{B}\cdot\operatorname{curl}\vec{A}-\vec{A}\cdot \operatorname{curl} \vec{B} = \operatorname{div}(\vec{A}\times \vec{B})$

Tags: vectors

$$\vec{B}\cdot \operatorname{curl} \vec{A}-\vec{A}\cdot \operatorname{curl} \vec{B} = \operatorname{div}(\vec{A}\times \vec{B})$$

So I started from the LHS as follows:

$$=B_i\epsilon_{ijk}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} A_k-A_i\epsilon_{ijk}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}B_k$$

$$= \epsilon_{ijk}\left(B_j\frac{\partial A_k}{\partial x_j} - A_i\frac{\partial B_k}{\partial x_j}\right)$$

I'm not sure if I've done these steps correctly, but assuming I have; I can't see where to go from here.

I know that $$\operatorname{div}\vec{A}\times\vec{B} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(\epsilon_{ijk}A_jB_k)$$

By the way I'm new to tensor notation, so please explain things you might think are obvious (because they probably aren't obvious to me). Thanks

Comment: is it $div \vec {A} \times \vec{B}$ or $div.(\vec {A}\times\vec {B})$  ?

Comment: @TheDeadLegend the second one

Comment: Differentiate using the product rule, flip a couple of indicies and you are there.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit I tried what you suggested, but I'm not sure how to flip the indices on terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Levi-Cevati symbol is antisymmetric in the interchange of any pair of indicies $ \epsilon_{ijk}= - \epsilon_{kji}$ and symmetric for a cycling of the indicies $ \epsilon_{ijk}=  \epsilon_{kij}$
Using the product rule 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\operatorname{div}\vec{A}\times\vec{B} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(\epsilon_{ijk}A_jB_k) =  \epsilon_{ijk}\frac{\partial A_j}{\partial x_i} B_k+  \epsilon_{ijk}A_j\frac{\partial B_k}{\partial x_i}.
\end{eqnarray*}
In the first term use $ \epsilon_{ijk}=  \epsilon_{kij}$ and  rename the indicies $k \rightarrow i $ ,$i \rightarrow j $ and $j \rightarrow k $.

In the second term interchange the indicies $ \epsilon_{ijk}= - \epsilon_{jik}$ nd  rename the indicies $i \rightarrow j $ and $j \rightarrow i $ .
\begin{eqnarray*}
 =   \epsilon_{ijk}  B_i \frac{\partial A_k}{\partial x_j}  -\epsilon_{ijk} A_i\frac{\partial B_k}{\partial x_j}.
\end{eqnarray*}